# Read several txt file from different directories in R

Tags: r, regex

I have several txt files in different directories. I want to read each file separately in R that I will apply some analysis on each one later.

The directories are the same except the last folder as the following:

```
c:/Desktop/ATA/1/"files.txt"
c:/Desktop/ATA/2/"files.txt"
c:/Desktop/ATA/3/"files.txt"
...
...
```

The files in all directories have the same name and the last folder starts from 1 to last order.

Answer (score 1):

Create all the filenames to read using `sprintf` or something similar. Then use `read.table` or whatever you use to read the text files.

```
lapply(sprintf("c:/Desktop/ATA/%d/files.txt", 1:10), function(x) 
           read.table(x, header = TRUE))
```

Replace 10 with the number of folders you have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```r
list_file <- list.files(path = "c:/Desktop/ATA", recursive = T, pattern = ".txt", full.names = T)
```

This will return the list of text files contained in your folder. Then, you can create a `for` loop to open them and apply some functions on each.

```r
for(i in 1:length(list_file))
{
   data = read.table(list_file[i],header = T, sep = "\t")
   ... function to apply
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a problem that the list.files are sorted as 1 10 c:/Desktop/ATA/1/"files.txt"
c:/Desktop/ATA/10/"files.txt"
c:/Desktop/ATA/2/"files.txt"                                                                                        How to solve this to be 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: @user225499, actually, I don't know... :( I will rather rename my folder in my environment before using R for processing files. Does the answer from Ronak Shah is giving you the same ordering issue ?

Answer (score 0):

First Thanks Guys, I mixed your codes and modified a little bit:

```
common_path = "c:/Desktop/ATA/"

primary_dirs = length(list.files(common_path)) # Gives no. of folders in path

list_file <- sprintf("c:/Desktop/ATA/%d/files.txt", 1:primary_dirs)
for(i in 1:length(list_file))
{
  data = read.table(list_file[i],header = T, sep = "\t")

}
```

So, by this way the folders are sorted based on 1,2,3 not 1,10,11,2,3.